# Pushologies SDK integration dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: ios, cocoapods, dyld, xcode14

Attempted to setup the project with Pushologies SDK via installed cocoapods per this documentation:
https://docs.pushologies.com/docs/3-xcode-project-configuration#cocoapods

And getting a crash on launch of the app with error:

```
Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/XXX_XXX_XXX_XXX/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXX_XXX_XXX_XXX/AppName.app/AppName
Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
```

I tried linking as static library by removing `use_frameworks!` and that did not help as it caused all sorts of issues with other pods.

Using Xcode 14.2 for build process.

Answer (score 1):

So after keep digging and reviewing my project settings I realized that the target that was being setup with Pushologies did not actually have the framework added in the general settings of the target. After manually adding PushSDK there with embed and sign option - the crash went away.